# If an endofunction is surjective and non-injective its domain is infinite

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, infinity

I'm currently reading about proofs and would appreciate some feedback on my attempted proof below.

"A surjective and non-injective function $ f : A \longrightarrow A$ exists if and only if A is infinite."

Consider the infinite set $A = \mathbb{N}$.

If A is infinite there exists a subset $S$ such that $S \subset A$ and $S \sim A$ (proper and equinumerous).

Suppose a function $ f : A \longrightarrow A$, such that

$f : a \mapsto  \left\{ 
\begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{a}{2} & \mbox{if  } 2\mid a   \\
{a} & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$

$f(1) = f(2) = 1,$ thus $f$ is not injective, but surjective.

The set of all positive even numbers $S = \{2n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} $ is a proper and equinumerous subset of $A$. $A$ is therefore infinite and the initial proposition is true.

Is this proof acceptable? Have I proved the "if and only if" as well?

Comment: I don't think it matters that $f$ satisfies the lemma you mention, but rather that you have a proper subset with the exact same cardinality as your original set. That's only possible in infinite sets.

Comment: @quickquestion4 I had misunderstood slightly what I was trying to prove. Edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: The informal proposition that you need to prove has $A$ as free variable. It is understood that what is meant is that the statement should be proven for all sets $A$. Your argument assumes $A=\mathbb{N}$ and does something, but then that means that we can't use it for other sets.

Comment: In other words, you have given an example of the proposition, but that's not the same as a proof. A proof of this proposition needs to address all possible sets $A$.

Comment: Use the pigeonhole principle to show that surjective endomorphisms on finite sets are injective. Then the result follows from the contrapositive.

Comment: @JohnDouma that sounds very  interesting and relevant. Hopefully it'll help me prove it for all possible sets!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood the statement that you are asked to prove.  It is meant to be read with an implicit universal quantifier on $A$, so it means

> *For all $A$*, a surjective and non-injective function $ f : A \longrightarrow A$ exists if and only if $A$ is infinite.

You have instead just given one example of a set $A$ which is infinite and has such a function.  This would prove the "if and only if" statement for that one particular value of $A$, but you need to prove it no matter what $A$ is.  (In any case, there would be an easier way to give an example of just one set for which the statement is true--you could instead pick an $A$ such that both sides are *false*, such as $A=\emptyset$.)